# Is their any better way to set duplicate array data instead of use data[0]

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

What is the best way to refactoring code and best performance Here Is what I do In getData function I query get Data from databae using async/await then I got some ugly data I try to map and delete element that duplicate data

```
async getData({req,res}) {
    let data = await this.getData() 
    data = [
      {
          "id": 3,
          "employee_id": 2290,
          "getId": {
              "id": 9070
          },
          "getName": {
              "name": "test"
          },
      },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "employee_id": 2291,
          "getId": {
              "id": 9070
          },
          "getName": {
              "name": "test"
          },
      }
  ]  //example I await call database get data look like this

  //before I remove them I want to keep duplicate data I set new variable for keep them
  //which part is the most ugly is their anyway to do something about this ?
    const getId = data[0].getId
    const getName = data[0].getName

  // in this part I map and delete element that duplicate which is data.getName and data.getId
  // I create seperate function for code clean
    data = await this.removeElement(data)

    //after that I return response data

    return response.status(200).json({
      status: 200,
      success: true,
      getId: getId,
      getName: getName,
      data: data
  });  
}




async removeElement(data) {
  // im not sure is their any beeter way to do something like this ?
   return Promise.all(
        data.map(async item => {
            await delete item.getId;
            await delete item.getName;
            return item;
        })
    );
}
```

so my output response will look like this :

```
 getId : {
      id : 9070
    }
    getName : {
      name : 'test'
    }
    data : [
      {
          "id": 3,
          "employee_id": 2290,
      },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "employee_id": 2291,
      }
  ]
```

I really appreciate for your help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing properties from an object is not an asynchronous process. There's no need to `await` it or have a `Promise.all` around such a loop.

To extract the two common properties from the first item of the array concisely, you can destructure:

```
const { getId, getName } = data[0];
```

Shorthand property names will help too. In full:

```
const data = await this.getData();
const { getId, getName } = data[0];
const trimmedData = data.map(({ id, employee_id }) => ({ id, employee_id }));
return response.status(200).json({
  status: 200,
  success: true,
  getId,
  getName,
  data: trimmedData
});
```

The `data.map(({ id, employee_id }) => ({ id, employee_id }))` takes the array and constructs a new array of objects which contain only the `id` and `employee_id` properties in the original objects.

If you need to *blacklist* properties rather than extract the desired properties, then you can do something similar to the above with rest syntax:

```
const trimmedData = data.map(({ getId, getName, ...rest }) => rest);
```

Comment: Is their anyway else insteadf of data.map(({ id, employee_id }) => ({ id, employee_id })); because I've 10 + element if I use map it will be like  f data.map(({ id, employee_id,employee_id2,employee_id3,employee_id4,employee_id5 })  and more haha